# nodejs websocket server unable to connect when moved to production

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have successfully implemented the following nodejs websocket server on my local machine, however when attempting to move it to production I am unable to connect(not sure if the server code is needed but I will include anyway):

```
var ws = require("nodejs-websocket");

var server = ws.createServer(function(conn){
    console.log("New connection");
    //conn.sendText("You are connected");

conn.on("text", function(str){
    //conn.sendText(str.toUpperCase() + "!!!");

    var inputOBJ = JSON.parse(str);

    if(inputOBJ.TYPE === 'USERNAME'){
        conn.username = inputOBJ.BODY;
    }

    if(inputOBJ.TYPE === 'MESSAGE'){
        //console.log("Connected User: " + conn.username);
        //console.log("Recipient: " + inputOBJ.RECIPIENT);
        //console.log("Body: " + inputOBJ.BODY);

        var userOnline = false;
        server.connections.forEach(function(connection){

            if(connection.username === inputOBJ.RECIPIENT){
                userOnline = true;
                var message = {};
                message.TYPE = "USER";
                message.BODY = inputOBJ.BODY;
                connection.sendText(JSON.stringify(message));
            }

        });

        if(!userOnline){
            var message = {};
            message.TYPE = "SYSTEM";
            message.BODY = "User is not online";

            conn.sendText(JSON.stringify(message));
        }

    }


});

conn.on("close", function(code, reason){
   //console.log("Connection closed"); 
});

conn.on('error', function(err){
    //console.log(err.stack);
});

}).listen(1337);
```

When I run the program on my server it acts like it's running as if everything were alright. After checking the ports by running command *netstat -lntu* I can verify that the port is open. The following is the row showing port 1337:

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1337            0.0.0.0:*            LISTEN

If there is anything else I can provide please let me know. As of right now I'm not sure why it will not accept connections???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be do to firewall rules set on the one of the networks I was testing from. When I connected from another network, everything functioned as expected.